# It is possible to sort the proccesses by a given date in bash?

Tags: bash, date, terminal, jobs, ps

All I'm trying to do is to sort the processes by an input date.
This is how I saved the date:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Insert the date yyyy-mm-dd"
read a
if ! [[ $date =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]
then echo "Date is not valid"
elif b=`date --date=$a '+%Y-%m-%d'`
then 
????
fi
```

How can I show the processes at this date? Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, There is no command to substitute that `???` with unless your OS periodically  saves process list somewhere

Comment: Wouldn't `b` and `a` presumably be identical in your code? What exactly are you trying to sort? I don't see any attempted sort in your code.

Comment: @oguzismail  I do not think it does that..

Comment: Then you're looking for something that doesn't even exist. You can write a program that periodically saves process list to a file though, then you can do whatever you want with its logs

Comment: @jordanm You are right. Now that you mention it, I do not know exactly why I did it. You do not see any attempted sort because I am not trying to sort them specifically, but to display them if they started at that date. I feel like I can't make myself clear because I don't quite understand the task. I've ask around, but to no avail. Here is the task: a shell script that displays the processes launched in the background at a certain date. The date is a positional parameter. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for your advice! I will try to do that.

Comment: @wantlolearn I think @oguz-ismail might be confused in thinking that you want to also return processes which have exited sometime in the past. I think you are just looking form something like `ps -eo lstart,pid,cmd --sort=start_time` to parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a formatter and use `lstart`, like this command:

```
ps -eo lstart,pid,cmd
```

The above command will output all processes, with formatters to get date+time, PID started, and command run, but i have changed the date format to be align with your date input

This is what you looking for :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A MONTHS
#months Dictionary

MONTHS[01]=Jan
MONTHS[02]=Feb
MONTHS[03]=Mar
MONTHS[04]=Apr
MONTHS[05]=May
MONTHS[06]=Jun
MONTHS[07]=Jul
MONTHS[08]=Aug
MONTHS[09]=Sep
MONTHS[10]=Oct
MONTHS[11]=Nov
MONTHS[12]=Dec

echo "Insert the date yyyy-mm-dd"
IFS="-" read -a val

if [[ "${val[0]}-${val[1]}-${val[2]}" =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]
then
    echo "Date is valid!!"
    ps -eo lstart,pid,cmd --sort=start_time | \
    awk {'print $5 "-" $2 "-" $3 " " $6 " " $7'} | \
    grep "${val[0]}-${MONTHS[${val[1]}]}-${val[2]}"

else
    echo "Date is not valid"
fi
```

output sample :

```
2020-May-19 23 [crypto]
2020-May-19 230 [scsi_tmf_27]
2020-May-19 231 [scsi_eh_28]
2020-May-19 232 [scsi_tmf_28]
2020-May-19 233 [scsi_eh_29]
2020-May-19 234 [scsi_tmf_29]
2020-May-19 235 [scsi_eh_30]
2020-May-19 236 [scsi_tmf_30]
2020-May-19 237 [scsi_eh_31]
2020-May-19 238 [scsi_tmf_31]
2020-May-19 239 [scsi_eh_32]
2020-May-19 2390 /usr/lib/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
```

Comment: My God! This exercise gave me a big headache..I can't thank you enough! I really appreciate your help. However, I didn't understand everything you did there - noob here, remember?:). So can you explain a little bit what is up whit all that numbers inside the awk command? Also, if they have the $ sign before them, does that mean they are positional parameters?

Comment: yes they are, so if you run this command `ps -eo lstart,pid,cmd` you will see the output format for each line as below `Tue May 19 15:41:12 2020   8339 [jfsIO]`, i just used awk to map them to be `2020-May-19 8339 [jfsIO]`

Comment: note: you can split a shell command over multiple lines by using `\`

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh since you're already calling `read`, might as well just split the input into an array based on the `-` as the field separator, as in: `IFS="-" read -a val`.  Now you can use `${val[0]}, ${val[1]}, ${val[2]}` instead of range parameter expansion

Comment: @SiegeX your approach better and readable more than mine, i will update the answer now